# How to fix AWS Device farm SDK error Unexpected key 'type' found in params

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-device-farm

I am trying to get the list of uploads in the AWS Device Farm. I tried to use the method **"devicefarm.listUploads"** from Lambda.

I am facing an issue when I am trying to filter it by type.

```
var uploadList = devicefarm.listUploads({ arn: deviceFarmProject, type: 'IOS_APP' }).promise()
  .then(res => res)
  .catch(err => err);
```

The expectation is to get data about all the iOS apps, but getting the bellow error.

```
{
    "message": "Unexpected key 'type' found in params",
    "code": "UnexpectedParameter",
    "time": "2019-05-02T15:49:35.351Z"
}
```

Comment: Where did you get the error?

Comment: What runtime is the Lambda function using? Node 8?

Comment: I put my code in Lambda and I can reproduce the issue. This suggests to me that the version of the aws-sdk in Lambda is not up to date to include the type parameter of the Device Farm sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~~I'm not sure why the type isn't recognized here~~

**[Edit]**

The reason for this error is due to the version of the aws-sdk in AWS Lambda. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

> Node.js Runtimes
>
> Name  Identifier  AWS SDK for JavaScript
>   Node.js 8.10
>
> nodejs8.10
>
> 2.290.0

I created a Lambda layer with the following commands and applied it to my function through the web console.

```
npm init
npm install aws-sdk
mkdir nodejs
cp -r node-modules nodejs
zip -r aws-sdk-layer.zip nodejs
```

**note** the zip file structure needs to match the Lambda documentation example. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html#configuration-layers-path

> Node.js – nodejs/node_modules, nodejs/node8/node_modules (NODE_PATH)
>
> Example AWS X-Ray SDK for Node.js
>
> `xray-sdk.zip
>   └ nodejs/node_modules/aws-xray-sdk`

after I applied the layer I was able to execute the function successfully.

---

but I used the following and it seemed to work though I didn't have any iOS uploads.

```
// assume we already executed `npm install aws-sdk`
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Device Farm is only available in the us-west-2 region
var devicefarm = new AWS.DeviceFarm({ region: 'us-west-2' });

var params = {};
devicefarm.listProjects(params, function (err, projects) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else{
        project = projects.projects[0];
        console.log("project: ", project);
        uploadList = devicefarm.listUploads({ arn: project.arn, type: 'IOS_APP' }).promise()
            .then(function(uploadList){
                console.log("uploads: ",uploadList);
            })
            .catch(err => err);
    }
});
```

**code I executed in Lambda**

```
// assume we already executed `npm install aws-sdk`
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Device Farm is only available in the us-west-2 region
var devicefarm = new AWS.DeviceFarm({ region: 'us-west-2' });

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var params = {};
        devicefarm.listProjects(params, function (err, projects) {
            if (err) reject(err); // an error occurred
            else {
                var project = projects.projects[0];
                console.log("project: ", project);
                resolve(project);
            }
        });
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log("in then function","data: ",data);
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            devicefarm.listUploads({ arn: data.arn, type: 'IOS_APP' }, function(err,uploads){
                if (err) reject(err); // an error occurred
                else {
                    resolve(uploads);
                }
            })
        }).then(function(data){
            console.log("uploads: ", data);
            return data;
        }).catch(function(data){
            console.error("list uploads failed","data: ", data);
            return data;
        });
    }).catch(function(data){
        console.error("list projects failed","data: ",data);
        return data;
    });

};
```

It might be the case that the aws-sdk version in Lambda isn't up to date in which case you would need to apply a [Lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) or include the aws-sdk in the code package.

Locally I executed this code and it provided the following output:

```
node sample.js
project:  { arn: 'arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:111122223333:project:00ec5d2a-9170-4c52-b65e-0e12986e4fc3',
  name: 'web_app_test',
  created: 2019-02-10T22:47:35.052Z }
uploads:  { uploads: [] }
```

aws-sdk version: `aws-sdk@2.448.0`

node --version
`v8.12.0`

HTH

James

Comment: I created a new layer with the latest version of the SDK. It worked perfectly. Thanks for putting your effort and finding me the solution.

Comment: I am able to start the remote session. If i don't stop it, the session is active for around 2.30 hrs. How to automatically stop it, if i forgot to end the session manually.

Comment: You should be able to stop it using this command and the sessions Arn. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DeviceFarm.html#stopRemoteAccessSession-property


Might want to look at step functions depending on use case.

Comment: I agree that we have a command to stop the remote session. What should I do if want to allow the user to use it only for 10 minutes? Should I try running a cron job? Your suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Then I believe there is a parameter for how long the session should last for in the create session command. You would set that to be 10 minutes and the session should die by itself.

Comment: I checked in the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DeviceFarm.html#createRemoteAccessSession-property couldn't find any such parameter.

Comment: You're right, so in that case you would need to implement some timer that's set for 10 minutes or some other value. Then call the Stop Remote access session API.

Comment: Seeing at AWS SQS, but I can delay only for 15minutes max, not sure what to do if I want to extend at least a few more minutes. Let me know anything pops up in your mind. Thanks, James.

Comment: I found a cool feature of remote access. According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-session.html#how-to-create-session-next-steps
> After a session starts, if you should close the browser or browser tab without stopping the session or if the connection between the browser and the internet is lost, the session remains active for five minutes. After that, Device Farm ends the session. Your account is charged for the idle time. 
So you could just not make a connection to the web socket anymore and the session will stop on it's own.